# GCC optimization -O1 exposes uninitialized error

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I am using gcc (ver 4.4.6) and -O3 optimization level with -Wall. If compile the same code with -O1 optimization level and -Wall, I see couple of new uninitialized warnings. 
The code has issues which is reported by -O1 and not by -O3. Ideally one expects to see more warnings and stricter checks at higher optimization.

Is this expected or I am hitting a gcc issue?

Thanks in Advance.

Following is the section of code.

```
int vrc_phy_locate()
phys_instance pinstance;
:
 select = SelectFlag();
 if (select == SELECTED) {
    pinstance = vrc_phy_locate_pinstance(canvas, x, y);
    if (pinstance) {
:
: 
    }
 }

select = SelectFlag();
if (select == SELECTED) {
    blackbox = vrc_phy_locate_blackbox();
    if (pinstance) {
        vrcPhySelectBlackbox();
:
:

 Following warning is seen on compiling with -O1
 canvas_util.c: In function 'int vrc_phy_locate(vbgCanvas*, int, int)':
  canvas_util.c:1223: warning: 'pinstance' may be used uninitialized in this function
```

Comment: gcc sometimes prints more warnings at higher optimization levels - because the compiler performs a more thorough analysis of the code - but the inverse is not expected. Can you post a minimal example of a program that produces this behavior?

Comment: This is not a minimal example of a program that produces the behavior, but a snippet from your full program. The difference is that the former would be compilable stand-alone.